# how to delete an object from list in dart

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, http

i want to delete an object from list of inventory in which i just have description and url of the inventory and i want to delete object of inventory by description so how can i delete the object.

function in service class

```
Future<dynamic> requestToRemoveInventory(
      String accessToken, List<TradeWithPictures> list) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.patch(Uri.parse(AppUrl.removeInventory),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'
          },
          body: jsonEncode({"inventory": list}));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return responseJson;
      } else {
        var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(responseJson);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw NoInternetException('No Internet Service');
    }
  }
```

Function Controller class

```
deleteInventory(List<TradeWithPictures> list, BuildContext context) async {
    String? accessToken = await preferenceService.getAccessToken();
    inventoryService.requestToRemoveInventory(accessToken!, list).then((value) {
      getMyInvenoryFromService();
    }).catchError((error) {
      showSnackBar(error.toString(), context);
    });
  }
```

please tell me what logic i have to write in view to delete the object. when i am deleting then all list is removed.

this is my view

```
PopupMenuItem(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                var list = inventoryController
                                                    .myInventoryList1
                                                    .where((i) =>
                                                i.description !=
                                                    inventoryController
                                                        .myInventoryList1[
                                                    index]
                                                        .description)
                                                    .toList();
                                                inventoryController
                                                    .deleteInventory(
                                                    list, context);




                                              },
                                              value: 1,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                    8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Delete",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: AppColors
                                                          .pinkAppBar,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.w700),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? it looks like you are using some api that does it or not? But I believe you are calling `getMyInvenoryFromService()` after it without storing the result. Am I correct? So do something with the result, just how you probably do it the first time you are handling `getMyInvenoryFromService()`.

Comment: all list is removing at a time

Comment: but i want to delete an item one time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can filter out your results from a list,

filteredResulst = AllRecords.where((i) => i.aParticularProperty === thingToCompare ).toList();